# Need to find repeated value in string in foreach loop in perl

Tags: perl, foreach

I am opening a file that contains a hash, and creating a string, and setting my string equal to the value of that key in the hash, so I may hold all containments of that hash key value inside my string. I am running this through a foreach so I get every value from the file's hash into my string:

```
open FN, '<', $file or die;

%hash = packageInt(); // this is the hash from the file I just opened above '$file'

foreach my $val (sort keys %hash) {

$id = $hash{$val}{id};

print "IDS: $id\n";


}
```

When I print $id, I get 5 values:

```
4353
7653
5431
4353
8769
```

I want to find the values that are repeated, in this case `4353` and DELETE them from my string variable `$id`, and reassign `$id` to only those values that are not replicated. In this case, `7653, 5431, 8769`. Because my criteria is not interested in doing tests on duplicate ids. I am having a hard time figuring out how to track the ID values that are duplicates and deleting them from the string because the string is in a foreach loop. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Always use `use strict; use warnings qw( all );`

Comment: What do you mean by "the hash from the file"? Files contain bytes, not data structures!

Answer (score 0):

You say "delete from a string variable", but you appear to mean "proceed to the next pass of the loop".

```
my %seen;
for my $val (sort keys %hash) {
   my $id = $hash{$val};
   next if $seen{$id}++;

   ...
}
```

Comment: I tried implementing your code and it didn't solve my problem. Could you perhaps give me a few more lines for guidance?